# React does not recognize the `classNameName` prop on a DOM element?

Tags: reactjs

at div
at ReviewSection
at div
at Home
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81213:5)
at div
at App
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:81146:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:79955:5)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Nobody can tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.  Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are writing 'className' as 'classNameName'.

PS: Format your questions properly and write proper details before posting. None of what you posted is useful in knowing what your actual problem is.